# Rshiny SIR model in Rstudio

Tags: r

I am trying to create an interactive plot using Rshiny and SIR() model. Basically, i want 5 slider inputs which are beta, gamma, S, I and R and output a plot of S, I, R across a specified time.

Below is my code in Rstudio. Ignore the fact that S+I+R should be equal to 1.

Any advice where the error is?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Sliders"),
    sliderInput(inputId = "gr1", "Beta:",
                min = 0, max = 3,
                value = 1.42),
    sliderInput(inputId = "gr2", "Gamma:",
                min = 0, max = 1,
                value = 0.142),
    sliderInput(inputId = "gr3", "S proportion:",
              min = 0, max = 1,
              value = 1 - 1e-06),
    sliderInput(inputId = "gr4", "I proportion:",
              min = 0, max = 1,
              value = 1e-06),
   sliderInput(inputId = "gr5", "R proportion:",
              min = 0, max = 1,
              value = 1e-06 + 1e-06),
  plotOutput("plot")
  )
  


server <- function(input, output){
  val <- SIR(pars = c(input$gr1,input$gr2), init = c(input$gr3,input$gr4,input$gr5), time = 0:70)$results
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    
    with(val, {
      plot(time, S, type = "l", col = "blue",
           xlab = "period (days)", ylab = "Proportion of people")
      lines(time, I, col = "red")
      lines(time, R, col = "green")
    })
    
    legend("right", c("susceptibles ratio", "infectious ratio", "recovered ratio"),
           col = c("blue", "red", "green"), lty = 1, bty = "n")
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: what is the SIR function?

Comment: And can you provide the error you get?

Comment: The solution below using reactive() is correct. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really cool graphs but the library has something very similar called `PlotMods`

```
library(shiny)
library(EpiDynamics)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Sliders"),
  numericInput(inputId = "gr1", "Beta:",
              min = 0, max = 3,
              value = 1.42),
  numericInput(inputId = "gr2", "Gamma:",
              min = 0, max = 1,
              value = 0.142),
  numericInput(inputId = "gr3", "S proportion:",
              min = 0, max = 1,
              value = 0.999999),
  numericInput(inputId = "gr4", "I proportion:",
              min = 0, max = 1,
              value = 1e-06),
  numericInput(inputId = "gr5", "R proportion:",
              min = 0, max = 1,
              value = 2e-06),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  parameters <- reactive(c(beta = input$gr1, gamma = input$gr2))
  initials <- reactive(c(S = input$gr3, I = input$gr4, R = input$gr5))
  
  # Solve and plot.

  val <- reactive(SIR(pars = parameters(), init = initials(), time = 0:70)$results)
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    
    with(val(), {
      plot(time, S, type = "l", col = "blue",
           xlab = "period (days)", ylab = "Proportion of people")
      lines(time, I, col = "red")
      lines(time, R, col = "green")
    })
    
    legend("right", c("susceptibles ratio", "infectious ratio", "recovered ratio"),
           col = c("blue", "red", "green"), lty = 1, bty = "n")
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```